how to select the current date in the pickerDate view
How to select the current date on PickerDate view when user just enter the page
my home page looking like this
    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    @State private var showDayView: Bool = false
    @State private var offsetY: CGFloat = -40
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("August")
                            .font(customFont(20, "-Medium"))
                        
                        Spacer()
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text("Calendar")
                        } label: {
                            Image("Calendar")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .padding([.horizontal, .top])
                    
                    .background(Color.accentColor)
                    
                    PickerDate(selectedDate: $selectedDate) {
                        self.singlePickedDate(date: $0)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                DayView(selectedDate: $selectedDate)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom)) 
                    .offset(y: offsetY)
            }

    func singlePickedDate(date: Date) {
        selectedDate = date
        withAnimation {
            showDayView = true
        }
    }

and My PickerDate looks like this to call the PickeDate View
struct PickerDate: View{
    
    @Binding var selectedDate: Date
    var onDateSelected: (Date) -> Void
    
    let daysOfWeek: [String] = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
    
    
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            ForEach(0..<7){ index in
                let day = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: index, to: startOfWeek())!
                VStack{
                    Text(daysOfWeek[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: day) - 1])
                        .font(customFont(15,"-Medium"))
                        .padding(.top,15)
                        .fontWeight(selectedDate == day ? .bold : .regular)
                    
                    Text(day, format: .dateTime.day())
                        .font(customFont(15,"-Medium"))
                        .fontWeight(selectedDate == day ? .bold : .regular)                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .background(selectedDate == day ? Color.white : Color.clear)         .clipShape(Circle())
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.bottom, 8)
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .background(selectedDate == day ? Color.deepAccent : Color.accentColor)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .onTapGesture {
                    onDateSelected(day)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.accentColor)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
    }
    
    func startOfWeek() -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let today = Date()
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: today)
        return calendar.date(from: components) ?? today
    }
    
}


I'm wondering why my onAppear doesn't works here?
Is that because when I passed selectedDate to the pickerDate view, the current date is not current any more?
but I tried to add a onAppear at PickerDate view too, it also doesn't work

Please show a [mcve] - some code that can be copy-pasted into a new project and reproduce your problem.

We have no idea what self.singlePickedDate is that you are updating in onAppear but shouldn't you be assigning a date value to selectedDate in onAppear where the property is declared?

@JoakimDanielson Sorry, I should double checked my code in  post next time, but  singlePickedCode is just the function that allows me to assign value to selectedDate

Your two views looks very similar, I assume neither is the PickerDate view. Please take some time to make sure the code you have posted is complete and the actual code we need to understand the problem as mentioned in the first comment.

@JoakimDanielson I messed up the code for the view. I put home view code for twice. Sorry. I updated the code for PickerView

The problem is that your selectedDate property has the time set to the current time while in the PickerDate view the local variable day has no time (it's 00:00.00) and therefore you will new get the two to match so all your checks for equality will fail
The easiest solution here is to set the time part of selectedDate to zero as well.
So in your main view change the initialisation of the property to
@State private var selectedDate: Date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: .now)


Thank you, it works smoothly after I fixed this
